# Zxing Scanner App, How to show a result as a yes or no?

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner

Using zxing on Android Studio with empty activity and 4.4 KitKat. I would like to show the result as a yes or no. I would like to reference a google sheet with the UPC codes. If the UPC is in the spreadsheet already then show "YES" or if the UPC is not in the spreadsheet show "NO". Can I use an "If, Else" in the MainActivity java code using only the UPC column on the google sheet?

```
@Override
        protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.getContents() == null) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

I want to show this code as a "Yes" or "NO" based on if the scanned barcode is already in the spreadsheet. My question is how to get the spreadsheet to communicate with the scanner or can copy all of the barcodes from the spreadsheet in a boolean?

```
Set<String> getStringSet (String key, 
            Set<String> defValues)

makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)

protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
            IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.getContents() == null) {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

So above is what ive come up with from search. Is it practical to use shared preference to store my data(1000 UPC) use ZXING to parse as well as IF ELSE to check the code and finally TOAST to show "YES" or "NO" based on if my result is located in the shared preference?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Activity activity = this;
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
            integrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            integrator.setCameraId(0);
            integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            integrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null) {
        if (result.getContents() == null) {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Cancelled scan");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Scanned");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

public void scanCode(View view) {
}

public class myWebView extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);



        WebView myWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);



        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("https://google.com/");
    }


    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override

        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

            startActivity(intent);

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What you want achieve exactly....you mean get call back from zxing and display in toast..???

Comment: If you want call back then it will get in onActivityResult method you will get.

Comment: Thanks I updated my question. I will use Toast to show "YES" or "NO" but how does Toast communicate with my spreadsheet?

Comment: In the show() can I put "YES" for example show(YES) to display "YES" Thank you in advance. My code is good with 0 errors and I am treating it delicately as it has taken a long time to get here.

Answer (score 0):

for segregation of code you need to create SacnActivity as a separate activity which is extend Activity and impliments ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler and call from the MainActivity and give call back to Mainactivity in onActivityResult().

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        scan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnScan);


        scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SacnActivity .class),1);

            }
        });


    }

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
                Log.d("result================>",""+result);

                try {
                    //processData(result);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question if you would like to share your thoughts on my "solution."

Comment: I mean you sacn barcode and  checking it is in spreadsheet or not if it is present then already present and if not then save inside that ..???

Comment: No I dont want to save it . If the barcode is not already in the data, then only display "NO". 1)Scan barcode, 2)check if it is in the data, 3)display yes or no.

Comment: So what you get from above your updated code is there any error or what by the way when you do scan procedure after that results is coming or not in onActivityResult method.